# Is the number of partitions of a parquet file in ADLS same as number of partitions after reading it as dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have 3 parquet files in ADLS

2 parquet files have 10 sub-parquet files and when i read it as a dataframe in databricks using pyspark, the number of partitions are equal to 10 which is expected behaviour.

3rd file has **172** snappy.parquet files and when i read it as a dataframe, the number of partitions are equal to **89**, what is the reason behind this?

Used this command **df.rdd.getNumPartitions()** to find the number of partitions of a dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading, Spark is trying to create Spark partitions of size not bigger than specified by `spark.files.maxPartitionBytes` (128Mb by default). When reading files, Spark will look for file size, and take it into account - when file size is smaller than desired partition size, then partition will be created from multiple files, and when file size is bigger than desired partition size, then it will be split into multiple partitions (if the format is splittable, like, Parquet).

In your case, it looks like you have a lot of files smaller than desired partition size.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Ott.  Total size of the file is 84 MB, each of those 172 partitions is less than 0.7 MB and they became 90 partitions after reading into a dataframe. So can I conclude when partitions are small then they can become any number of partitions after reading just that spark will make sure that the any partition after reading is not greater than 128 MB